# Expo Go not working properly after update

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, ios-simulator, npm-install

I recently updated my expo sdk from 39 to 41.

Ever since the update, everytime i run `expo start` and I try to run the app on both ios and android simulators I get the error below:

[image]

Is there anyway to solve this or downgroade to sdk 40 or something? I don't even know that format the app is in

Comment: does this happen on any new project? if you `expo init` something new. if not, can you try try to narrow down the cause? this might help: https://expo.fyi/manual-debugging

Comment: @brentvatne Hi tahnks for your response. No this does not happen on a new project off expo init. It is just this recently updated project.

Comment: try this approach to narrow it down: https://github.com/expo/fyi/blob/master/manual-debugging.md#disassemble-and-reassemble

Comment: @brentvatne I tried following that. I think the issue is that the error came immediately after i updated the expo app to sdk 41 so there was no way to even dismantle and work through each step

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below command when you want to start your app.

```
expo start --offline
```